# angular: cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, api

I keep getting the error of `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` in my HTML component

```
<button (click)="getRecipeDetails()">Show</button>
 
<div>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.id"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.title"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.summary"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.dishTypes"></div> <br>
</div>
```

Here is the code that I made in the component TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  recipeInformation:Recipe;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  // Get Recipe Details:
  getRecipe(id:any='782698'): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('apiKey',Constants.API_KEY)
    
    return this.http.get(URL,{params}).pipe(
      map(json: Object) => [json].map(jsonItem => Recipe.fromJson(jsonItem)))
    );
  }
  getRecipeDetails(){
    this.getRecipe().subscribe(
     recipes => this.recipeInformation = recipes[0]
    )
  }
```

And here is my recipe.ts class:

```
export class Recipe{
    
   constructor(public id: number,
                public title: string,
                public summary: string,
                public dishTypes: []) {
    }
     public static fromJson(json: Object): Recipe {
        return new Recipe(
            json['id'],
            json['title'],
            json['summary'],
            json['dishTypes']
        );
    }
}
```

After I click the **Show** button, the data gets retrieved fine, but this error keeps showing up, before and after I make the call to the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `RecipeInformation` is undefined at this point:

```
recipeInformation:Recipe;
```

You can use an `*ngIf` to help.

```
<button (click)="getRecipeDetails()">Show</button>
 
<div *ngIf="recipeInformation"> 
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.id"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.title"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.summary"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation.dishTypes"></div> <br>
</div>
```

Or use the safe navigation operator:

```
<button (click)="getRecipeDetails()">Show</button>
 
<div>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation?.id"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation?.title"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation?.summary"></div> <br>
    <div [innerHTML]="recipeInformation?.dishTypes"></div> <br>
</div>
```

Learn more about the safe navigation operator [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/angular-6-by/9781788835176/e80649ae-4986-46b1-898d-04c39796a18c.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your model is configured wrong, to fix it change it:

```js
export class Recipe{
   id: number
   title: string
   summary: string
   dishtypes: []
    
   constructor(public id: number,
                public title: string,
                public summary: string,
                public dishTypes: []) {
                
                this.id = id
                this.title = title
                this.summary = summary
                this.dishTypes = dishTypes
    }
     public static fromJson(json: Object): Recipe {
        return new Recipe(
            json['id'],
            json['title'],
            json['summary'],
            json['dishTypes']
        );
    }
}
```